# Parse CSV file and perform conversion in Linux

Tags: linux, unix, csv

I have a big CSV file (several 100 MBs) with lots of columns:

```
1;18Jun2013;23:58:58;;;l;o;t;s;;;;o;f;;;;;o;t;h;e;r;;;;;c;o;l;u;m;n;s;;;;;
```

You see the second column is a date that I'd like to have in format %Y-%m-%d for easy insertion and ordering in a database. I believe it's easier and faster to convert the raw data instead of later in the database.

The main script is using bash. For now I've proceeded as follows for the conversion:

```
  sed -n '2,$p' $TMPF | while read line; do
        begin=$(echo "$line" | cut -d\; -f1)
        origdate=$(echo "$line" | cut -d\; -f2)
        #cache date translations, hash table for the poor
        eval origdateh=h$origdate
        if [ "x${!origdateh}" = "x" ]; then
        # not cached till now, need to call date, then store
            datex=$(date -d "$origdate" +%Y-%m-%d)
            eval h$origdate="$datex"
        else
        # cache hit
            datex=$(eval echo \$h$origdate)
        fi
        end=$(echo "$line" | cut -d\; -f3-)
        echo "$begin;$datex;$end" >> $TMPF2
    done
```

I use sed to start with the second line (1st line contains CSV headers) and I believe all the subshells with the echos and cuts slow things down, so the "hashtable" really is not of much use...

Who can make this go fast?

Comment: `Who can make this go fast?`: Only you by using a dedicated CSV parser.

Comment: does this have to be done in bash?  If you used something with better array/split/join implementation than the shell (I'm thinking ruby/perl/python) you could probably get significant speed increase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use a bash script but a Python script. At the very least, this will be much more readable/maintainable and probably more efficient.

Example code could look like this (untested):

```py
# file: converter.py

import datetime

def convert_line(line):
    # split line on ';'
    line = line.split(';')
    # get the date part (second column)
    # parse date from string
    date = datetime.date.strptime(line[1], '%d%a%Y')
    # convert to desired format
    # replace item in line
    line[1] = date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    # return converted line
    return ';'.join(line)

while True:
    print convert_line(raw_input())
```

Now you'd just do:

```py
cat file.csv | python converter.py > file_converted.csv
```

Alternative implementation:

```py
# file: converter_2.py

import datetime

def convert_line(line):
    # split line on ';'
    line = line.split(';')
    # get the date part (second column)
    # parse date from string
    date = datetime.date.strptime(line[1], '%d%a%Y')
    # convert to desired format
    # replace item in line
    line[1] = date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    # return converted line
    return ';'.join(line)

with open('file.csv') as infile, open('file_converted.csv', 'w+') as outfile:
    outfile.writelines(convert_line(line) for line in infile)
```

Example usage:

```py
python converter_2.py
```

If you have some header lines in your csv, you must not convert them with this function, of course.

Comment: The speed of that is very much to my liking (700 MB file in a few minutes).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, I tried the first example, the following seems to work just fine when called from within a bash script.

```py
# file: converter.py
import datetime
def convert_line(line):
    # split line on ';'
    line = line.split(';')
    # get the date part (second column)
    # parse date from string
    date = datetime.datetime.strptime(line[1], '%d%b%Y')
    # convert to desired format
    # replace item in line
    line[1] = date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    # return converted line
    return ';'.join(line)
while True:
    try:
        print convert_line(raw_input())
    except (EOFError):
        break
```

Use

```py
tail +2 FILE | python csvconvert.py > xxx
```

to skip the header.